# Ubercart admin invoice: Show attribute prices

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I need to modify my admin invoice template to include each ordered product's base price AND any selected attribute prices.

For example:

> The product **Baseball Glove** is $50.
>
> The optional attribute **Glove oil** is $5.
>
> When a customer selects the attribute, it makes the total product
>   price $55.

Currently, the admin invoice shows just the product's total price along with a list of it's selected attributes. **How can I display both the base price ($50) and attribute price ($5) for each ordered product on the invoice?** Also, this would need to be scalable to work for products with multiple attributes.

Here is the current code we are working with in the admin invoice:

```
<p>
<b>Products ordered:</b><br />
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
&emsp;<span style="color:red;"><?php print $product->qty; ?>x</span> <?php print $product->title; ?> (<b>SKU:</b> <?php print $product->model; ?>) - <?php print $product->total_price; ?><br />
<?php if (!empty($product->data['attributes'])): ?>
<?php foreach ($product->data['attributes'] as $attribute => $option): ?>
&emsp;<?php print t('@options', array('@attribute' => $attribute, '@options' => implode(', ', (array)$option))); ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</p>
```

Which appears like this when rendered:

```
Products ordered:

1x Baseball glove (SKU: BB-1) - $55.00
Glove oil
```